# Use a Web Service to Run SQL queries for a Windows Forms Client

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

I need to use a Windows application running on remote clients that will connect to a web service. The web service will access an SQL database to verify users, and roles, and perform other tasks. I am using ASP.NET Membership to manage the users and roles. I have ASP.NET Membership, and the web service working on the development machine. I have a windows client with a service reference that works when I access methods that do not access the database, but when I try to access a service method that access a database method I get **The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.** I get various permissions errors depending on what I am try to fix this, but this is the gist. I don't want the Windows client to need DB permissions. I want it to send a user name, and password to the web service, then the web service wraps **Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)**

Can someone tell me how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider setting up SQL Server to use SQL and Windows Authentication (mixed mode).  It's most likely running in Windows Authentication mode only.  You can take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) link to get started.

It sounds like, by the way you have it designed, is that you would have to set up an account for each user.  In my experience it's best to just create a specific SQL account with the necessary permissions, and have each client use that account.  You could specify this in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have named pipes authentication enabled in SQL, your SQL connection string in your ASP.NET application could be configured to use integrated security (`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;`). Then in SSMS, give the appropriate ASP.NET user privileges to the database. The user that IIS uses depends on what version of IIS you're running, and can be seen in the App Pool configuration for the server in question.